# Haversine Function - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, haversine

I am trying to write a code where I am creating a haversine function to calculate the distance of a dataset containing different properties from the nearest hospital using their geolocation and this is what my code looks like:

[code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3QzoD.png)

However, I get this error which I don't understand as I am using lat2 and ids and have defined it whilst creating the function.

Could someone help me understand the error and probably, fix it too?

[hospital dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6YEiw.png)

[property details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9Tk1.png)

Comment: See [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`haversine_hospital` expects 5 inputs: lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2, ids

You have only given it 3: lat1, lon1, j(ids presumably).

You need to give it the X and Y coordinates of some other target that you want to calculate the distance from.